# React and Firebase : Get User information by UID

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, authentication, uid

me again. 
I'm trying to get user data from Firebase. I have de UID, anyone knows how i can get the data? 
I'm using react and y don't know how to get this. Thank you!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you include your code in the question?

Comment: Please follow the recommendations on [how to ask with this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

- My document name is 'users'. When I register a user I took that UserId and put that in local storage and then using that UserId, I created a new Object associated with userId.

  ```
  'database 
  .ref('users/' + uid)
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        this.setState({
          ## SET YOUR STATE ##
        });
      });'
  ```